# How do I populate a Google Spreadsheet with default values?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google Spreadsheet with 4 columns, I want a function that populates the columns with default values and another function that empties all the cells but keeps the column headers.

Comment: What code have you written so far? Can you show us what hasn't worked?

Answer (score 0):

These seems to be pretty basic functions. You have to try to develop them yourself. Have you read the Apps Script [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) and [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles)?

Stackoverflow is a place for you to ask programming related doubts, not to ask for entire programs!

Answer (score 0):

This basic function will populate your spreadsheet with X number of values in the first column:

```
function populateSpreadSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var line=ss.getLastRow()+1;
  var length = 550;
  for(i = 0;i < length;i++){
    ss.getRange("A1:A" + length).setValue("some value");
  }
}
```

A similar call to clearContent() should empty the cells.